# Efficient nested set comprehension in clojure

Tags: performance, clojure, set, data-mining

I have a list of 100 transactions, each containing 100 items.  I need to find the most frequent sets of items that appear together.  One of the things I have to do a lot to accomplish this is calculate the [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Useful_Concepts) of various itemsets among the transactions. Support is defined as the number of transactions containing all items in an itemset.

Here is my test data:

```
(def transactions '(#{1 2 3 4}
                    #{2 3}
                    #{1 3 4}
                    #{3 4 5}))
(def itemsets #{#{2 3}  ; Support should be 2
                #{3 4}  ; Support should be 3
                #{5}    ; Support should be 1
                #{3}})  ; Support should be 4
```

And here's my initial attempt at implementing a function that returns a list of all frequent itemsets:

```
(defn support [itemset data]
  (count (filter #(subset? itemset %1) data)))

(defn all-frequent [itemsets transactions min-support]
  (filter #(<= min-support (support %1 transactions)) itemsets))
```

And calling my all-frequent function:

```
(all-frequent itemsets transactions 3) ;=> (#{3} #{3 4})
```

Is this the most efficient and idiomatic way of doing this? I have considered other data structures like hash-set, sorted-set, etc, but I'm still pretty new at Clojure and I don't know the difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your current implementation is quite idiomatic. How is its performance on the actual production data? I ask because frankly, the size of your production data doesn't sound that huge that it would warrant micro-optimizing the implementation. After all, a simple, straight-forward implementation is much easier to maintain than a complicated optimized one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought there's probably a good solution involving storing your transactions in the form of a map of maps keyed by canonically sorted subsets, like a prefix tree, maybe using priority-map or finger-tree as the underlying map...sorry, that's not really a proper answer is it!